# SQL JOIN query to get data with GROUP BY on one table only

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to fetch data from multiple table where i have one product with its details distributed in multiple tables. Here is one query i am using:

```
SELECT 
    fp.id, fp.name, fp.slug, fp.status, fp.approved, fp.created_at, fp.updated_at,
    fc.name as cat_name, fc.slug as category_slug, 
    ff.filepath,
    fdp.type, fdp.sku, fdp.regular_price, fdp.sale_price

FROM `foduu_products` fp 

JOIN `foduu_category_product` fcp 
ON fp.id = fcp.product_id

JOIN `foduu_filemanager` ff 
on fp.filemanager_id = ff.id 

JOIN `foduu_categories` fc 
on fcp.category_id = fc.id 

JOIN `foduu_details_product` fdp 
ON fp.id= fdp.product_id 

where fcp.category_id in (39,155,30,41,51)

group by fdp.product_id           <<<<--------------------  Here is the problem

ORDER by fp.id ASC
```

When i am using `GROUP BY` to get data from `foduu_details_product` where it hold multiple records for one `product_id`. When i am running this query i am getting this error.

```
#1055 - Expression #8 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'foduu-ecommerce-cms.fc.name' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

Not understanding why GROUP BY always give me these short of errors. Any suggestions how can i improve my query here?

Here is my database tables SQL for reference:

http://vbought.com/products%20table.sql

Thank you (in advance)!

Comment: Can be there more than one `fc.name` per `fdp.product_id`?

Comment: it will be common fc.name for all fdp.product_id (per id)

Comment: You don't have any aggregate functions so group by is not appropriate see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html for more details and why you are getting an error.

Comment: then use `max(fc.name)` to avoid the error

Comment: Which of the foduu_details_product would you want? Perhaps you could put foduu_details_product into a sub query rather than a direct join.

Comment: @RadimBača still same

Comment: @P.Salmon i am not getting you

Comment: @user3201500 I don't think so, I guess the error target different attribute no?

Comment: Your version of mysql will not allow you to group by on 1 column only please read the link i sent you.

Comment: Do you want all foduu_details_product or only 1?

Comment: all foduu_details_product @P.Salmon

Comment: Is there any platform where i can show a demo of this database? Like there is jsfeddile, is there something for SQL as well?

Comment: sqlfiddle will do.But the group by seems to serve no purpose it would help if you could show your expected output.

Comment: @P.Salmon  i have just attached a SQL table data. I am using MySQL  5.7

Comment: A simple way to solve non aggregated columns: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40578865/439171

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any aggregate function in your query so you should question the use of this specific statement in the first place.

You are in "sql_mode=only_full_group_by", thus you have to repeat every column in the select that is not use in an aggregate function (Max,Sum,Count...) in the group by statement.